# Reverse Not Found Error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-1.5

If I have a URL Like this:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uid>\w+)/(?P<token>\w+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name="reset_password")
```

and a URL tag like this:

```
{% url 'reset_password' uid=uid token=token %}
```

Why do I get this error when I try to render the page in which the tag is contained:

```
Reverse for 'reset_password' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments not found
```

The both the uid and token are valid strings.

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: And you're able to visit the URL in the website fine?

Comment: Try debugging in a shell with `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` and then `reverse('reset_password', kwargs={'uid':uid, 'token':token})` see if you get more info. Also, if your url conf is part of an app, make sure it's included in the main url conf.

Comment: it sends me back the proper url (/reset/uid/token/) when I run it in the console.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid values in `uid` and `token` variables in context in your template?

Comment: How are you receiving values in those variables? Can you provide some code relating to it?

Comment: my guess is that token and or uid variables do not exist in the context, try showing them, adding this somewhere else on the same template  {{token|pprint}} {{uid|pprint}}

Comment: Can you output the uuid and token format? do they actually get matched at the regexp? Usually this error happens if the pattern does not match the arguments.

Comment: In Django 1.6 therse are : uidb64,token . And try to add comma in your arguments. Try that like this: 
url 'reset_password' uid64=uid,token=token .

Comment: Solved? If not please show your urls.py...

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your uid or your token has a non alphanumerical char like "-" or "." So I would try to change the urls.py to:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uid>.+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name="reset_password")
```

I don't like using the . in regex but If you have not oteher choices...

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

1.always try to namespace your url like`'app_name:reset_password'` with adding just

`app_name='your app name'` at the beginning of your urls.py file this will help you in future if you are handling multiple apps in same project when the names of your html are conflicting at same time

2.try this changes in your urls , as you are using django auth views and its password reset function you need specify redirect url also after resetting your password for that just add

```
{'post_reset_redirect':'<app_name>:<url_name>'}

url(r'^reset/(?P<uid>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'post_reset_redirect':'<your redirection url after reset password'},name="reset_password")}
```

And yes please check the variables also like 'uid' because as  it is django's own function might be it own variable name so try 'uidb64'